# GuzzleHttp post with JSON

Tags: php, guzzle

What is the correct way to sent json as multipart form in guzzle. From the code below it should be possible to iterate through `userComment` from the posted page. For eg: `userComment[0]` should give `{'name' => 'Jon', 'comment' => 'jons comment'}` and `userComment[0]['name']` should print `Jon`. But it is not working.

```
$response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
        'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'action',
            'contents' => 'addComment',
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'userComment',
            'contents' => ['json' => ['name' => 'Jon', 'jons comment' => 'Please']]
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'userComment',
            'contents' => '{name: "mike", comment: "mikes comment"}'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Documentation says that `Contents` should be of string, hence `'contents' => '{name: "mike", comment: "okay"}'` will work, but then I will have to do `$data = json_encode(userComment[1])` to get `$data['name']` as `mike` which doesn't looks like the correct way of doing. Any help, thanks!